# What is that complex property "All properties > data > properties" good for?

Tags: xpages

This is just out of curiosity: looking for some other type of property inside an xpage I stumbled upon "All properties > data > properties". This is a complex prop, multiple parameter elements can be added in sets of name > value pairs.

I tried to add a sample parameter here resulting in

```
<xp:this.properties>
    <xp:parameter
        name="param"
        value="val">
    </xp:parameter>
</xp:this.properties>
```

Rendering that page in a browser shows no changes at all, neither in the page's html source nor somewhere in the http headers, DOM trees etc.

Can anyone shed a light what this property set could be used for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The xp:view this.properties accepts xsp.properties options like the Xsp Properties editor in an application in Domino Designer, and like the options in the file C:\Domino\data\properties\xsp.properties.sample

For example:

```
<xp:this.properties>
    <xp:parameter name="xsp.client.validation" value="false"></xp:parameter>
</xp:this.properties>
```

will disable client-side validation for the current XPage, so that only server-side validation occurs.

Some options will be ignored when set in the xp:view on an XPage, e.g.

```
xsp.theme=oneuiv3.0.2
```

can only be set in the application xsp.properties or in the server-wide xsp.properties, and will be ignored if it is set in the per-XPage xp:view this.properties.

Comment: Thanks for the info Maire!

Comment: Many thanks, helpful as ever! One additional question though: is there a list of properties available that would *not* be supported like that example of yours? And while I'm at it:is there something like a comprehensive list of properties that come with the basic XSP controls?

Comment: The list of xsp.properties options is in the server xsp.properties.sample file, and in the book XPages Portable Command Guide. Whether they can be configured per XPage will vary from option to option - to check you'd set the option in the XPage and see if it has any effect; it's not specifically documented anywhere.

Comment: For the list of tag properties that can be set on the xp: control tags, see XPages-Doc.zip in the ExtLib openNTF releases. It lists the available tags and properties, with the description from the tooltip that appears in the Designer All Properties tab. That doc was last updated for the 9.0.1 Domino release. (To programmatically get the property lists, see ApplicationEx.getRegistry() or the XPages junit framework TestProject.getRegistry)